# Displaying not equal to

Tags: sqlplus

```
select DISTINCT STORECODE, SUPPCODE from stocks
where suppcode = 'S2'
```

From this code I get the Storecodes that have the supplier code 'S2'.

I would like to display where:

```
where suppcode != 'S2'
```

However, when I run this I then get the other store codes. e.g. S1, S3, S4, S5, S6. I would like to only return the Storecodes that don't have S2 as a supplier.

Many thanks!

Comment: I am confused. Looks like your query returns storecodes that don't have S2 as supplier. Did you word this correctly?

Comment: @Maxqueue There are 6 Suppliers: S1 - S6. Some of these suppliers don't supply the stores (there are 5 different store codes). When I run the query != 'S2' it displays all the other suppliers. If a store has been supplied by S2, I want to remove them. As more than 1 suppliers can supply 1 store.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct storecode
from stocks
where storecode not in 
    (select distinct storecode
     from stocks
     where supplier = 'S2')
```